# Can I control where in the toilet bowl the flush water goes?

Tags: toilet

When I flush the toilet the water mostly comes in from the front of the bowl. Is there something I can do so it covers more of the back?

[image: water coming in from the front]

There are more and bigger holes toward the front of the bowl:

Rear:
[image]

Front: 
[image]

Comment: Usually there are outlets for the water all around the underside of the rim.  Is it possible that ones in the back are clogged with some mineral buildup?  You might check with a mirror and try cleaning them out.

Comment: It is possible that some commercial demineralizer or toilet bowl cleaner could be poured down the overflow tube in the tank (which is how water gets into the under rim openings). Of course, there is some possible risk of this causing damage to the plastic, but I doubt it would. Use a mirror to examine the underside of the rim. If the openings are clogged then you should see it. Maybe your toilet does not have openings there.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks for the suggestion! It seems like the rear holes are smaller by design, added some more pictures.

Answer (score 1):

This is the design of the toilet. This pushes any solids and paper to the “well” in the back. If you don’t think you have enough flow a product like CLR can be used (turn water supply off, flush put clr in tank and flush” you may want to use a towel to keep the clr in the holes for a bit longer , then turn water back on and see if that opened things up. CLR is a product that dissolves Calcium, Lime & Rust. It works quite well on plumbing fixtures and I have done the above procedure to clear the rust stains so the toilet looked better for longer.